# How to add a button to card-view of bootstrap table plugin?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn - plugin for a project of mine and I want to add a bootstrap button to the card view of this plugin which is anchored to an email address retrieved from the database. Though I know how to add the anchor, I am unable to get the button to appear in every card.

Comment: I tried putting the button code surrounded by the <th> tag and also in a new <tr> tag, neither worked.

Comment: ok show the code on your question then i can easily help you

Comment: you are using bootstrap version 1.8.1, it has itself basic drawbacks so please use the higher version

Comment: Am using bootstrap 3.3.1, not 1.8.1. The page in my question might have linked to an older version of the plugin's docs but I believe there is a link to a newer version.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you need exactly , Please can you elaborate little more and also show the code what had you tried for this, So its Easy for me to Figure out your problem and find the solution.

Comment: I found a work around, thank you for offering to help.